# Laravel saving a model from a custom Event Subscriber

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-4

When I try to Save a model from a EventHandler then the `if( $event->save() )` always return false.

Any reason behind this? The $event is a user Model as I expect it to be.

```
<?php namespace AppName\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthEventHandler {

    public function onUserLogin($event) {
        $event->login_token = Hash::make('XXXX');
        if( $event->save() ) {
            dd(true);
        } else {
            dd(false);
        }
    }

    public function onUserLogout($event) {
        $event->login_token = null;
        $event->save();
    }

    public function subscribe($events) {
        $events->listen('auth.login', '\AppName\Auth\AuthEventHandler@onUserLogin');
        $events->listen('auth.logout', '\AppName\Auth\AuthEventHandler@onUserLogout');
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is automaticly called from the Auth class I guess. If I do a `dd($event)` then I get a User object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I were using https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation as my extending class to the User object which made a validation cause error.